# Using standardized normal distribution to find probability

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

"The number of nails in a carton is $N(563.3, 33.2)$. The distributor guarantees that the number of nails is more than $n$ with a probability of 99%. Decide n."

I've tried to make this into the standardized normal distribution with $P(Z >\frac{n-563.3}{33.2}) = 0.99$ but I don't know where to take it from there, or if this even is a correct way to tackle this problem. Some hints and help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct way. You need corresponding quantile for normal distribution - ie such value $x$ that $P(Z > x) = 0.99$. It's probably assumed that you take it from [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Quantile_function) (note that there are two-sided quantiles - $0.98$ two-sided quantile is equal to $0.99$ one-sided) or from some calculator like [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.99+quantile+of+normal+distribution).

Comment: Ah, so by looking in a table I find that $\lambda_{0.99} = -2.32643$ which then gives me that $n=486$?

Comment: Correct. Actually it's a bit more then $486$, so $P(X > 486)$ is a bit more than $0.99$ (but $P(X > 487)$ is already less than $0.99$).

Answer (score 1):

Let $X\sim \mathcal N(\underbrace{563.3}_{\mu}, \underbrace{33.2}_{\sigma^2})$.

The probability that the number of nails is more than $n$ is:
$$\mathbb P(X>n)=0.99 \iff \mathbb P(X-\mu>n-\mu)=0.99 \iff \\
\mathbb P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}>\frac{n-\mu}{\sigma}\right)=0.99 \iff \\
P\left(Z>\frac{n-563.3}{\sqrt{33.2}}\right)=0.99 \iff P(Z>-2.3263479)=0.99 \Rightarrow \\
\frac{n-563.3}{\sqrt{33.2}}=-2.3263479 \Rightarrow n\approx 549.9$$
Now, let's see the neighborhood of $n=549.9$:
$$\mathbb P\left(Z>\frac{549-563.3}{\sqrt{33.2}}\right)=0.9935;\\
\mathbb P\left(Z>\frac{550-563.3}{\sqrt{33.2}}\right)=0.9895.$$
Hence, the smaller $n$, the higher the probability. So, for $n\le 549$, the probability of having more than $n$ nails is at least $0.99$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ represent the random number of nails in a carton.  Then, when the distributor guarantees that the probability there are more than $n$ nails in a randomly selected box is $0.99$, this means $$\Pr[X > n] = 0.99.$$  Standardizing, we get $$\Pr\left[\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} > \frac{n - 563.3}{33.2}\right] = 0.99.$$  What is the value of $z^*$ corresponding to $\Pr[Z > z^*] = 0.99$?  Right away, you should note that $z^* < 0$, which means that $n$ should be less than the mean value $\mu = 563.3$.  This makes sense because if $n = \mu$, then there would be only a $0.5$ probability of a randomly selected box having more than $n$ nails.  The smaller $n$ is, the more likely you'll get a box with more than $n$ nails.